# How to add dynamically dots in the end of a string/sentence in Crystal Reports using Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I am designing a report using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio and I don't know how to add dynamic dots in the end of each line of sentence.

The code below is the example I found here but it is not justifying the lines, i think because i am using a static value for the length of my string and i don't know how to put it dynamic.
Note: I did use the method on "Format Object" but it's not working.

```
local numbervar stringlength;

stringlength := 194-length({EmissaoLicenca.DispostoOrganicoLicenca});

if stringlength >0
then 
({EmissaoLicenca.DispostoOrganicoLicenca} +replicatestring(".", stringlength))
else
{EmissaoLicenca.DispostoOrganicoLicenca}
```

I am expecting that the end of my lines should be like:

> This line is the example of a text line to be displayed...........................................

Answer (score 0):

What do you get instead of what you expect?

Your code sample is probably not the full code because it doesn't seem to be using the second declared variable.

In general, you should proceed by isolating the issue. For example, return just the value of the stringlength variable and see if it is correct.

Comment: When it is more than one line I get something like this.


"RUA DA SÉ, Nº 114, 6º ANDAR, PESTANA ROVUMA, , CIDADE DE MAPUTO - MOCAMBIQUE, TEXTO ADICIONAL......................................................................................................................................................................"

It jumps to the next line without justification.


But it should be like:

"RUA DA SÉ, Nº 114, 6º ANDAR, PESTANA ROVUMA, CIDADE DE MAPUTO - MOCAMBIQUE, TEXTO ADICIONAL...................................................................................................."

Comment: And thanks for the observation on the unused variable.
The code is complete without that extra unused variable.

P.S. the text is not static, it changes depending on what exists in the database.

Comment: It "jumps" to the next line because you don't have a space between the last character the the dots.